# How to restrict user adding people into slack channel using Slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to restrict users to add another user into channel. All I want is if I am adding a new user into a channel a notification triggers to the admin and once admin approves it then only that user can be added. Is this possible in Slack using Slack API. If yes, then what can be the workflow for this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Following APIs can be used to achieve the same

- channels.kick for Public channels
- groups.kick for private channels